# Windows Store App Heirarchical Navigation Template makepri compile error

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to get the HeirarchicalNavTemplate compiling on my machine in VS2013. Simply unzipping the template (available at http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Windows-Store-hierarchical-4b1c67c4#content) results in the following compilation errors:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: HierarchicalNavTemplate, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>  HierarchicalNavTemplate -> C:\Users\rw3\Downloads\Windows Store app hierarchical navigation%2c start to finish2\C#\bin\Debug\HierarchicalNavTemplate.exe
1>MakePri : error 0x80004005: Processing Resources with error: Unspecified error
1>C:\Users\rw3\Downloads\Windows Store app hierarchical navigation%2c start to finish2\C#\Strings\en-US\Resources.resw : error 0xdef00502: MakePRI: root node not found.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Turning up MSBuild logging level to diagnostic reveals that the offending command in question is

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x64\MakePri.exe" New -ProjectRoot "C:\Users\rw3\Downloads\Windows Store app hierarchical navigation%2c start to finish2\C#\\" -ConfigXml obj\Debug\priconfig.xml -OutputFile "C:\Users\rw3\Downloads\Windows Store app hierarchical navigation%2c start to finish2\C#\bin\Debug\resources.pri" -IndexName adf73318-7321-478b-9e3a-899a435c2a85 -Verbose -Overwrite
```

The relevant `priconfig.xml` file referenced in the command is pasted here: http://pastebin.com/s3BZWvbS.

The relevant `Resources.resw` file referenced in the command is pasted here: http://pastebin.com/TEKPGveq.

Both files seem to be OK and pass XML validation for syntax. Anyone's insight is appreciated.

Comment: Seems like makepri doesn't handle commas in a file path well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't like the HTML escape character `%2c` in the path

Rename the directory

```
C:\Users\rw3\Downloads\Windows Store app hierarchical%2c navigation start to finish2
```

to

```
C:\Users\rw3\Downloads\Windows Store app hierarchical navigation start to finish2
```

Comment: Yeah, It's the **%2c** problem.